# How to create custom plugin for Joomla 3.3

Tags: joomla3.3

I have a site on Joomla 2.5 with hikashop 1.5 and for recurring payment from eway payment gateway I have custom code on file /plugins/hikashoppayment/eway/eway.php, and this is working perfectly on my one live site  www.clet.edu.au

Now I have another site on joomla 3.3 with hikashop 2.3 and I want to use same previous custom code for same file /plugins/hikashoppayment/eway/eway.php, so how can I integrate existing custom code in current site please help me how to do this for joomla 3.3 plugin.

Comment: The site doesn't work this way, and do not provide links to tutorials. You may want to show your current trial to solve the problem. See [ask].

Answer (score -1):

You can use Custom HTML module application for creating modules or plug in for your website. This is very good application.

Comment: Custom HTML module is for **HTML** in a **module** and has nothing to do with a plugin.